# Using console.log() in Electron app

Tags: electron

How can I log data or messages to the console in my Electron app?

This really basic hello world opens the dev tools by default, by I am unable to use `console.log('hi')`. Is there an alternative for Electron?

**main.js**

```js
var app = require('app');
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');

require('crash-reporter').start();

var mainWindow = null;

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  // Mac OS X - close is done explicitly with Cmd + Q, not just closing windows
  if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('ready', function(){
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600});

  mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');

  mainWindow.openDevTools();

  mainWindow.on('closed', function(){
    mainWindow = null;
  });
});
```

Comment: Just a small note for whoever stumbles on this: Dev tools are also supported in `<webview>` tags as well via the openDevTools() method as documented [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/webview-tag/#webviewopendevtools)

Answer (score 210, accepted):

`console.log` works, but where it logs to depends on whether you call it from the main process or the renderer process.

If you call it from the renderer process (i.e. JavaScript that is included from your `index.html` file) it will be logged to the dev tools window.

If you call it from the main process (i.e. in `main.js`) it will work the same way as it does in Node - it will log to the terminal window. If you're starting your Electron process from the Terminal using `electron .` you can see your `console.log` calls from the main process there.

Comment: Can i `console.log()` to main process from the renderer process?

Comment: @FandiSusanto, You can use ipcRenderer module to send a message to your main process and, then, console.log() inside it.

Comment: What abut in production mode , what will` console.log() ` in main process do

Comment: @JimmyObonyoAbor To attach a console to a __production__ electron app and get the console output in your terminal run the following in a terminal`./path/to/release/MyProgram.app/Contents/MacOS/MyProgram`. This will run the binary `MyProgram` and allow you to view the process `console.log` events in a terminal.

Comment: how can i still log stuff to terminal after resetting the app via `app.relaunch()` and `app.exit(0)`???

Comment: I call it from neither, and nothing shows up. I have a page that has its own JS script, and I found that not only `console.log` stops working, but also VSCode syntax check stops working.

Comment: in a production electron app, running the setup.exe didn't have any cmdprompt output, but my program.exe did have cmdprompt output by using console.log in electron.js, without any special environment variable

Answer (score 71):

You can also add an environment variable in windows:

```
ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=1
```

This will output console messages to your terminal.

Comment: I didn't see any messages in the console until this environment variable was set.

Comment: The [docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/environment-variables.md) say that should be set to `true` and that setting it to `true` "prints Chrome's internal logging to the console", which is not what OP wants.

Comment: @pushkin It works with `ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=1` as well. And as for what the OP wants, what is it then? Take a look at the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/08f43367eaacb3793b8d33044022571e) to see the effect.

Comment: Which file is the ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=1 added to?

Comment: @Still_learning you set it as an environment variable. so from Windows command line `set ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=true`

Answer (score 39):

There is another way of logging to the console from inside the renderer process. Given this is Electron, you can access Node's native modules. This includes the `console` module.

```js
var nodeConsole = require('console');
var myConsole = new nodeConsole.Console(process.stdout, process.stderr);
myConsole.log('Hello World!');
```

When this code is run from inside the renderer process, you will get `Hello World!` in the terminal you ran Electron from.

See https://nodejs.org/api/console.html for further documentation on the `console` module.

Comment: It works for me only if I don't use `console.log` in `main.js` at all

Answer (score 21):

Yet another possibility is accessing the main process console using [`remote.getGlobal(name)`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/remote/#remotegetglobalname):

```js
const con = require('electron').remote.getGlobal('console')
con.log('This will be output to the main process console.')
```

Comment: This works great, but how can we catch the entire console output; ie- without having to call a special function; such that exceptions and errors are also output ?

Comment: Derrick: Try setting the environment variable `ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=1` (see deejbee's answer)

Comment: I'm trying to use inside a background script for an extension, and it's not working, unclear as to why. (background scripts get loaded in as background windows, basically)

Answer (score 16):

Adding to M. Damian's answer, here's how I set it up so I could access the main process's console from any renderer.

In your main app, add:

```js
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const console = require('console');
...
app.console = new console.Console(process.stdout, process.stderr);
```

In any renderer, you can add:

```js
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const app = remote.app;
...
app.console.log('This will output to the main process console.');
```

Answer (score 14):

```js
process.stdout.write('your output to command prompt console or node js ')
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Now that's what I call the answer, one straight line !

Answer (score 10):

You can use the npm package electron-log https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-log

It will log your error, warn, info, verbose, debug, silly outputs in your native os log.

```js
var log = require('electron-log');

log.info('Hello, log');
log.error('Damn it, an error');
```

Answer (score 10):

Sorry to raise an old thread but this is the top result for "how to output console.log to terminal" (or similar searches).

For anyone looking to gain a bit more control over what is output to the terminal you can use `webContents.on('console-message')`:

```js
mainWindow.webContents.on('console-message', (event, level, message, line, sourceId) => {
    console.log(message + " " +sourceId+" ("+line+")");
});
```

See:

[webContents Documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents)
[webContents entry on BrowserWindow docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winwebcontents)

Answer (score 7):

This is what I use:

```js
let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(/*...*/) // Your browser window

function log(...data) {
    mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript("console.log('%cFROM MAIN', 'color: #800', '" + data + "');");
}
```

Example use (same as `console.log`):

```js
log('Error', { msg: 'a common log message' })
log('hello')
```

Source: https://github.com/fuse-box/fuse-box-electron-seed/tree/master/src/main in the logger.js file, here you can see a real use case.

Comment: Data needs to be encoded though (as JSON string?) to avoid JS code injections.

Answer (score 6):

This is a follow up to cscsandy5's answer for some addition information, info from [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout)

```
process.stdout.write('your output to command prompt console or node js ')
```

This code works great for just outputting a simple debug message to the terminal window you launched the electron app from and is is what console.log is build on top of.

Here is an example snippet (based on tutorialspoint electon tutorial) of a jQuery script that will write hello to the terminal every time the button is pressed (warning: you need to add your own line breaks in the output strings!)

```
let $ = require('jquery')
var clicks = 0;

$(function() {
    $('#countbtn').click(function() {
        //output hello <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        process.stdout.write('hello')

        $('#click-counter').text(++clicks);
    });

    $('#click-counter').text(clicks);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

After some investigation, here my understanding:

## Code

(1) main.js

```js
const createPyProc = () => {
  console.log('In createPyProc')
...
  console.log('scriptStart=%s', scriptStart)
...
  console.log('scriptOther=%s', scriptOther)
...
}

...

let mainWindow = null

const createWindow = () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(
    {
      width: 1024,
      height: 768,
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
      }
    }
  )
  mainWindow.loadURL(require('url').format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}
...
```

Note: which use `openDevTools` to opened `Electron Dev Tools`

(2) render.js

```js
const zerorpc = require("zerorpc")
...
    console.log("clientStart %d server is ready", PORT_START)
...
})
```

(3) `render.js` is called by: `index.html`

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
  <script>
    require('./renderer.js')
  </script>
</html>
```

## `console.log`

### Output Logic

- **two process** and its **console.log** output:

  - `main process` = `NodeJS process` = here `Electron UI process`

    - -> `console.log` in `main.js` will output log to here
  - `render process`

    - -> `console.log` in `render.js` will output log to here

### Screenshot Example

- **DEBUG=Development** mode

  - run `./node_modules/.bin/electron .`

    - [image]
- **Production=Release** mode = the **xxx.app** pacakged by `eletron-builder`

  - run `/path_to_your_packaged_mac_app/xxx.app/Contents/MacOS/yourBinaryExecutable`

    - [image]
  - added `export ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=true`, `render.js` console.log **ALSO** output to `main process` terminal

    - [image]

Answer (score 4):

`console.log()` will work fine for debugging. As the `electron` is built on top of browser, it has `DevTools` support you can use devtools for debugging purpose. However, there is a hysterical behaviour of `console.log()` method. When you call the `console.log()` from `main process` of electron app, it will output to the terminal window from where you just launched the app and when you call it from `renderer process` it will output to the DevTools console.

Answer (score 3):

Everything [Alex Warren wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31759944/1531971) is true. Important here is how Electron is started. If you use the standard script in the *package.json* file it will not work. To make `console.log()` work replace the old script with this new one.

Old one:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
}
```

New one:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": ".\\node_modules\\electron\\dist\\electron.exe ."
}
```

Now all `console.log()` calls are displayed in the terminal as well.

Comment: you save my day!!! on win server 2012 it's the only way to make console.log work!

Answer (score 3):

With this You can use developer tools of main Browser window to see logs

```js
    function logEverywhere(s) {
        if (_debug === true) {
            console.log(s);
            // mainWindow is main browser window of your app
            if (mainWindow && mainWindow.webContents) {
                mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`console.log("${s}")`);
            }
        }
    }
```

Example `logEverywhere('test')`
will output `// test` in console panel of main browser window's developer tools

You may need enhance this method to accept multiple args (You can done it with spread operator by es6)

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is 2019 and I cant believe no one mentioned this trick in all the answers above.
Ok, so, how about logging directly to the browser console directly from the main?
I provided my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58913251/8764808
Take a look.

Comment: Thanks @Wale! Would you mind inlining your answer? I don't mind the link to another question, but a lot of mods on here get pissy about cross linking answers even with SO.

Comment: I would have actually loved to, but again, the last time I tried doing that, I was reprimanded for duplicating answers.

Answer (score 1):

A project I'm working on was using [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate). That has `electron-devtools-installer@2.4.4`, which somehow via `cross-unzip` causes a process to crash with `Error: Exited with code 9` .

Upgrading to `electron-devtools-installer@3.1.1`, as [proposed in electron-react-boilerplate@v2.0.0](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/pull/2661/files#diff-7ae45ad102eab3b6d7e7896acd08c427a9b25b346470d7bc6507b6481575d519R217) resolved it so my `console.log`, `console.error`, etc statements worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

for log purpose, i would recommend you to use the [electron-log](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-log) package