# Enable logging in electron app for windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, console, electron

I am using the [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) app with a windows machine. I have added logging statements in the main.js as follows:

```
const electron = require('electron')
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

console.log("Test");

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
  console.log("Test");
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

In the package.json file I have replaced the line `"start": "electron ."` with the line `"start": "electron . --enable-logging"` Here is what I get when I call `npm start`.

[image: electron logging]

Where is my mistake? How can I enable logging under windows?

Comment: Logs from the main process should appear in the console you started Electron from. The `--enable-logging` flag should not be necessary.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot it does not appear.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: The npm command. If you called the electron.exe explicitly everything worked just fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759367/using-console-log-in-electron-app

Answer (score 2):

set environment variable `%ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING%`

Comment: Not sure if it was like this when this original comment was posted, but from the Electron docs https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/docs/api/environment-variables.md :  `ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING`: "Setting this variable is the same as passing --enable-logging on the command line." So, I do not believe setting this env variable will have an effect if `--enable-logging` is not working.