# Writing to terminal in node.js / electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, electron

I'm new to Electron. Just trying it out today, to port a simple single-page app I have in CoffeeScript to it.

To debug something I tried console.log but nothing appears in the terminal that I launch the app. from. Is there a way to write to the terminal from inside node.js / electron?

I'm running the program with

```
npm start
```

which I guess is a wrapper for

```
./node_modules/.bin/electron .
```

But I'm guessing both suppress writing to stdout. (In node itself console.log seems to write to stdout)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759367/using-console-log-in-electron-app

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31759367/5647260)? Might help.

Comment: OK. I see what the issue is. Is there a library or something that can (even from inside the "browser" part of the app) write to the console?