# console.log() function stopped working on Electron app Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, electron, console.log

Until recently I've used console.log extensively in Electron, both from code and monitoring results in the Developer Tools console, and also by typing `console.log("something or other")` directly in the Developer Tools console.

All of a sudden it's no longer working.  Nothing happens when running console.log() from a JS script, and if I type console.log("test") in the Developer Tools console the response is "undefined".  console.log by itself (no parentheses) shows `ƒ (){}` as opposed to `function log() {[native code]}`, which perhaps explains the lack of functionality?

Trying to figure out how that might have happened and how to resolve it -- did I accidentally click on some preference or setting somewhere?  Quite the PITA to lose that.

Comment: It's possible to override `console.log` with some other function (e.g. an empty function to disable log output in production). Maybe an imported module does that? Try a log statement at the beginning of your renderer script, before importing stuff.

Comment: You didn't accidently deselect the `Info` selection in the `Default levels` dropdown menu near the top right-hand corner of the DevTools window? If  you did, you can just select `Default` from the dropdown list and it will reset the `Info`, `Warnings` and `Errors` logging levels.

Comment: @midnight-coding thanks - That's the kind of thing I though I might have somehow accidentally clicked, but I'd checked those, and all is fine there.

Comment: @snwflk - Thanks Yes, I'm aware of that & checked the code for something that might have changed it. On further digging it turns out `console.info`, `console.error`, `console.warn` -- none of these work and all show the `ƒ (){}` as opposed to `function () {[native code]}` BUT `console.debug`, `console.dir`, and perhaps most interestingly `console.context().log()` all DO work just fine. That effectively solves the problem in my use case. But considering I don't use any of those others in my code, it leaves quite the mystery about what's going on.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion to add a `console.log('test')` before any imports? If that works, you know something later in the renderer code causes the override.

Comment: Tried that indeed.  console.log is dead from the start.

Comment: This link ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759367/using-console-log-in-electron-app ) suggests console.log might, by default, be logging to a terminal stdout whereas console.context().log() definitely logs a browser developer tools console.

Answer (score 0):

where console.log() stopped working

console.context().log() is the alternative command that so far has been working.